# Depickling from a version number that is higher than our version

Tags: python, pickle

I have a problem with rdkit and spark. I gives me an error 
Depickling from a version number (9.0)that is higher than our version (7.2)

I am using conda, I tried to update pickle (I thought maybe that is the problem) however it seems that conda does not have pickle.

Can anyone provide some direction please with regards to the source of the problems. Thanks

Comment: `pickle` is a standard module, every Python distribution should have it.

Comment: `pickle` is part of the standard library; the version number you see is not a `pickle` version number (there are only [4 protocol revisions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format)).

Comment: What versions of Conda and rdkit are you using? You appear to have a version mismatch of *something else* in your setup.

Comment: The error message is coming from rdkit; it stores information in pickle to communicate, and the way that information is structured is versioned. Make sure your rdkit versions *across your cluster* is compatible.

Comment: Conda version 4.5.4, conda build version 3.10.5 , python version 2.7.15 and rdkit version 2018.03.2

Comment: Thanks, For now I am using spark on local (only 1 pc) therefore versions across cluster should not be a problem at this stage.